# Combine variables in Azure Devops Build Pipeline YAML

Tags: docker-compose, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I'm creating a docker build and push task in an Azure Devops Build pipeline YAML file, and I'd like to tag the image with the combination of two variables, the project name and the build number, so the tag would be service_22 (service is the project, 22 is the build number).

How do I join two variables together, e.g. $(variable)_$(variable2)

```
- task: Docker@2
  inputs:
    containerRegistry: 'Azure'
    repository: 'jdmcontainers'
    command: 'buildAndPush'
    Dockerfile: 'Dockerfile'
    tags: |
      $(Build.BuildId)
      $(imageName)
```

That's the current file, the tags are added as individual separate tags.

Comment: did you try '$(variable)_$(variable2)' ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with below format:

```
steps:
- task: Docker@2
  displayName: buildAndPush
  inputs:
    xxxx
    tags: '$(System.TeamProject)_$(Build.Buildid)'
```

`$(System.TeamProject)` is one environment variable which can get the current project name.

---

[image]

Answer (score 38):

For those who come here and are actually looking for a way to **combine** two **strings/variables** in the **job variable declaration**, you can use the **`format()` expression** ([docs link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions#format)):

```
- job: Build
  variables:
    job_variable: $[format('Hey-{0}', variables['Build.Reason'])]
```

I hope this helps someone, at least I searched for this for hours and found nothing. ^^

Answer (score 0):

Try this it works in Azure pipeline yaml

```
parameters:
 - name: String1
   displayName: StringName
   type: string
   values: 'Hello '

variables:
- name: String2
  value: 'World'

- name: StringConcat
  value: ${{parameters.String1}}${{variables.String2}}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: How to concatenate in a loop like concatenating values in a loop and assign to variable?